# Как правильно прервать foreach при уменьшении его списка?

Tags: c#, unity3d

При переборе foreach уменьшается размер его списка list_inventory. Ошибка

> InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration
>   operation may not execute.
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[Assets.scripts.GUII.Inventory.InventoryItem].VerifyState
>   () (at

Если foreach обвернуть while, то GUI исчезает или зависает:

```
while(w==true)
{foreach ...}
```

Как правильно прервать foreach при уменьшении его списка?

```
public void OnGUI()
    {
        ...
                GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(200, 75, 190, Screen.height - 100), GUI.skin.box);
                {
                    ...

                    foreach (InventoryItem item in list_inventory) //уменьшается список 
                    {
                        GUILayout.BeginVertical(GUI.skin.box);
                        GUILayout.Label(item.index.ToString()); 

                        if (GUILayout.Button("<- "))  
                        {                   
                                    ...
                                    list_inventory.RemoveAt(i); //удаляется элемент списка

                            }
                            //
                        }
                        ...
                        GUILayout.EndVertical();
                        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                        GUILayout.EndVertical();
                    }


                    GUILayout.EndScrollView();
                }
                GUILayout.EndArea();

            }

            else
            {
                if (GUI.Button(new Rect(200, 50, 190, 25), "Show Inventory"))
                {
                    showInventory = !showInventory;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: лучше не использовать `foreach` если ожидается изменение коллекции

Comment: Сделайте for с перебором от последних к первым -- при удалении элементов это самый удобный способ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый легкий способ это

```
            foreach (InventoryItem item in list_inventory.ToList()) //преобразуем лист в другую коллекцию, промежуточную
            {
                  ...
                  list_inventory.RemoveAt(i); //удаляется элемент списка оригинальной коллекции.

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Решено как здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/412876/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-foreach)
Но коллекция заместила предыдущую после foreach

Чтобы решить эту проблему, нужно вместо присвоения ссылки

```
incoming = outcoming;
```

создать новую коллекцию с теми же элементами

```
incoming = new List<Position>(outcoming);
```

Comment: Попробуйте через `for` ... работает с ним.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно удалить элемент(ы), тогда нужно делать итерацию в обратном порядке и вы сможете удалить элемент с конца списка

```
var data = new List<string>(){"Yo","Two", "Yo", "Three"};
for(int i = data.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
    if(data[i] == "Yo")
    {
        data.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

то есть в юнити как-то так:

```
public List<string> data = new List<string>() { "Yo", "Two", "Yo", "Three" };

public void OnGUI() {
    for (int i = data.Count - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        GUILayout.Label(data[i].ToString());
        if (GUILayout.Button("<- ")) {
            data.RemoveAt(i);   
        }
    }
}
```

но, как жалуется @Pavel Mayorov в комментариях, при таком обратном цикле и вывод будет обратным... чинится это просто:

```
for (int i = data.Count - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    var index = data.Count - 1 - i;

    GUILayout.Label(data[index].ToString());
    if (GUILayout.Button("<- ")) {
        data.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Кстати, сам удивился, но даже при прямом проходе **именно в цикле for** все равно будет работать. Т.е. код

```
public void OnGUI() {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++) {
        GUILayout.Label(data[i].ToString());
        if (GUILayout.Button("<- ")) {
            data.RemoveAt(i);   
        }
    }
}
```

валиден, за исключением случая, когда может быть несколько подряд идущих элементов, которые надо удалить, в этом случае нужно уменьшить счетчик при удалении, в противном случае следующий элемент за удаленным пропустится.

```
public void OnGUI() {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++) {
        GUILayout.Label(data[i].ToString());
        if (GUILayout.Button("<- ")) {
            data.RemoveAt(i);   
            i -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Обратите внимание: автор же рисует элементы списка! Нельзя так просто взять и развернуть обход в обратном направлении...

Comment: @PavelMayorov и что? ГУЙ обновляет все и перерисовывает. не вижу никаких проблем http://s018.radikal.ru/i512/1607/d2/971abea38de2.gif

Comment: @PavelMayorov более того.....оно с `for` и в прямом порядке сработает

Comment: Если разбить цикл на два (обновление и перерисовку) - то да, проблем нет. Но простого разворачивания цикла, как у вас в ответе написано, недостаточно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov не понимаю. при удалении, по сути, список пересчитывается. А на новом кадре гуя этот уже обновленный список перерисовывается (Тот код который в ответе спокойно работает, о чем свидетельствует та гифка с демонстрацией работы без бросания каких-либо ошибок)..... Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: если развернуть цикл - то порядок вывода элементов на экран тоже развернется - а это ошибка!

Comment: @PavelMayorov  Это уже никак не относится к вопросу)))..... если я напишу `for (int i = data.Count - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            GUILayout.Label(data[data.Count - 1 - i].ToString());
            if (GUILayout.Button("<- ")) {
                data.RemoveAt(data.Count - 1 - i);
            }
        }` ........или же даже напишу прямой `for`, т.к. он тоже работает - вы от меня отстанете?)))

Comment: @PavelMayorov добавил это в ответ...только не говорите, что это не сработает

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в прямом `for` это работает до того момента пока не будут подряд идти две кнопки `GUILayout.Button("<- ")`, так как при удалении первой, элементы сдвинулись, счетчик увеличился и вторая кнопка пропустилась. Решение может быть откат счетчика при удалении элемента

Comment: @Grundy а зачем нужны подряд две кнопки `GUILayout.Button("<- ")` ?  Типа `Удалить` и `100% ТОЧНО УДАЛИТЬ`  ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не могу сказать :-) мало ли что может быть, но в этом случае - вторая пропустится

Comment: @Grundy вот именно, что **мало ли что может быть**. Может 5 кнопок подряд ,а может все вразноброс, а может чтоб нажать надо отсылать смс *УДАЛИСЬ, ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, ПОГАНАЯ КНОПКА!!! АААА!!!* на номер 7272 ... Гадать нет смысла. А играть в экстрасенса я как-то не настроен. Так что работает.

Comment: Работает, кроме случая, когда два элемента которые нужно удалить идут подряд :)

Comment: @Grundy не вижу такого случая в вопросе автора. Значит всё идет так, как задумано..... Есть решения, которые подходят для достижения результата одной задачи, но не подойдут для другой. Универсального решения на все сферические задачи в вакууме - нет.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, но если он вдруг появится, то решение сломается. Фактически решение - зависящее от содержимого коллекции - не очень хорошее

Comment: @Grundy ну если так не нравится могу удалить этот пункт

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, лучше добавить предупреждение в каком случае он может не сработать и как его тогда поправить, чтобы заработал

Answer (score -2):

Что бы прервать foreach нужно вызвать break.

```
var length = item.Length;
foreach(var item in items)
{
   // что-то делаем

   if (items.Length != length)
   {
       break;
   }
}
```

**Но так лучше не делать**, перепроектируйте код так, что бы список при переборе всегда был фиксированной длины. И тогда вы избавитель от нежелательных трудно находимых ошибок.

**Дополняю**, eсли хочется удалять элементы из перебираемой коллекции то нужно создать новый список (коллекцию) и перебирать уже её, а удалять из оригинальной:

```
var list = new List<T>(originalCollection);
foreach(var item in list)
{
    if (условие для удаления)
    {
        originalCollection.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Пример для автора вопроса:

```
var items = new List<InventoryItem>(list_inventory);
foreach (InventoryItem item in items) //уменьшается список 
{
    GUILayout.BeginVertical(GUI.skin.box);
    GUILayout.Label(item.index.ToString()); 

    if (GUILayout.Button("<- "))  
    {                   
        ...
        list_inventory.Remove(item); //удаляется элемент списка

    }

    ...
    GUILayout.EndVertical();
    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    GUILayout.EndVertical();
}
```

Comment: Обратите внимание: автор же рисует элементы списка! Нельзя так просто взять и прервать обход или развернуть его в обратном направлении...

Comment: Автор также в заголовке своего вопроса спрашивает совершенно конкретную вещь. "Как правильно прервать foreach..?". А то что автор решил вывести меняющийся список это отдельная история. Я так же написал, что лучше перепроектировать решение для вывода уже статического списка. InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified - это не только частная проблема в конкретном месте, это проблема проектирования приложения.

Comment: Евгений, у вас в ответе этой безусловно верной и полезной информации написано не было.

Comment: "Но так лучше не делать, перепроектируйте код так, что бы список при переборе всегда был фиксированной длины. И тогда вы избавитель от нежелательных трудно находимых ошибок."

Comment: Слишком непонятно для новичка. Да, так всегда лучше. Но *как*?!

Comment: В случае когда меняется только количество элементов в коллекции то перед перебором нужно создать новые либо массив  либо список: var newList = new List<T>(list);

Comment: Кстати посмотрел ещё раз код автора вопроса он сам перебирая список из него же и удаляет. Так что проблема решается перебиранием новой коллекции, а удалением из реальной. Дополню свой ответ.